# How can I add a string to a string value inside an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What im trying to do is to add a string id next to a value inside of an object.
So the object is like this:

```
["John","Mike"]
```

An item in the object is generated as soon the user clicks an add button

```
  const handleAddClick = () => {
    setLanguage([...language, ""]);
  };
```

```
  const handleItemChanged = (event, index) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const list = [...subtitle];
    if (list.filter((f) => f === value).length > 0) {
      setErrorValidation("Names cannot be equal!");
    } else {
      setErrorValidation("");
    }

    list[index] = value;
    setName(list)
  };
```

In the handleItemChanged, I tried to do this, but it didn't work.

```
let string = "test"

list[index] = value + string;
setName(list)
```

So what I want is to add a string to a new value that is added to the list

```
["Johntest", "Miketest"]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: use map? `list.map(e => e+urString)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` before assigning value:

```
// ... the other code is omitted for the brevity
list.map(item => item + "test") 
setName(list)
```

An example:

```js
let arr = ["John", "Mike"]
arr = arr.map(item => item + " test")
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setName(list)` does not trigger a rerender for the simple reason that `list` is still the same object. `setState` will only work if the previous and new value is different. For objects, they are shallowly compared.

That is why it is suggested to create a new array using `.map()`:

```
let string = "test"
const newList = list.map(e => e+urString)
setName(newList)
```

Comment: Tried your login, but it seems not to work. Every time I type, the ```string``` is added to the value. exp: ```["Johntesttesttest"]```